# Изменение кредов для базы в Gradle

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

Есть Java проект, сборка производится с помощью Gradle.
В проекте есть тесты, которые в том числе проверяют и работу с базой.

Есть файл hibernate.xml в котором настройки для базы.
Как сделать так что б параметры к базе логин/пароль/сервер можно было задать через командную строку gradle build?

Comment: ` -Pmyprop=myvalue ` не подходит ?

Comment: А hibernate вместо значение прописать ${myprop} ?

Comment: не совсем. прописать  ${myprop}, если  ${myprop} нет, то прописать дефолтное значение

Comment: Строчка из hibernate: <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">${my_user}</property>  запускаю с параметром -Pmy_user=test_user не глотает его, в редиме Debug вижу что оно пробует подключится к базе без пользователя. Что не так не подскажете?